DuckDB: importing a Polars dataframe containing an `Enum` column turns it into a `VARCHAR` column in DuckDB?
import polars as pl

values = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series("x", values, dtype=pl.Enum(values)))
print(df)

shape: (3, 1)
┌──────┐
│ x    │
│ ---  │
│ enum │
╞══════╡
│ a    │
│ b    │
│ c    │
└──────┘

import duckdb as ddb

ddb.sql("SELECT * FROM df").show()

┌─────────┐
│    x    │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ a       │
│ b       │
│ c       │
└─────────┘

Why does DuckDB not convert polars Enum into a DuckDB Enum?
(Initially, I was trying to read from a polars dataframe I had saved as a parquet file on disk. On doing so, I ran into the same issue, and I wondered if the problem might have something to do with reading from parquet files, but the issue exists "reading directly" from polars too.)

Is there a question here?  SQL does not support enumeration types.

@TimRoberts DuckDB does: https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/data_types/enum.html

@TimRoberts I missed the question; thanks for pointing that out. Just applied an edit to address that.

@dydev I might be misunderstanding, but I do show this: ddb.sql("SELECT * FROM df").show()?

Testing pandas e.g. df_pd = df.to_pandas() - duckdb reads that okay and creates an enum type. It seems the polars support for that feature is just not implemented. Probably needs to be discussed on their Github.

One way to circumvent the issue would be to replace the last call to ddb.sql() with these two calls:
ddb.sql("create type et as ENUM (SELECT x FROM df)")

ddb.sql("SELECT x::et FROM df").show()

With your data, this produces:
┌─────────────────────┐
│    CAST(x AS et)    │
│ enum('a', 'b', 'c') │
├─────────────────────┤
│ a                   │
│ b                   │
│ c                   │
└─────────────────────┘

Alternatively, if you know the enum values beforehand,
you could avoid consulting df.

Yeah, this is what I am considering too. But I am not sure if this is an answer because it does not explain why DuckDB loads a polars Enum as a DuckDB VARCHAR.

You might like to propose a DuckDB enhancement.
